# CouchDB memory consumption rising over time

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, couchdb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a **CouchDB (2.3.1)** on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server with 1GB of memory.
While my Node app constantly consumes around 35MB, the CouchDB memory usage increases over time (Server restart at 12PM):
[image]

My running processes (sorted by memory usage):
[image]

Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: I don't see an "increase over time", except for the big jump at 6pm. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, it increased from 12PM to 6PM (after startup), then the jump at 6PM. Now it stays at ~88%.

Comment: So the question is what is causing this jump? Can this be throttled/would it be a good idea to throttle or do I simply need more memory?